# is there a way to enable clickable urls for iebrowser warnings?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Is there a way to enable clickable urls for IE browser warnings? I usually use Chrome and when Chrome encounters js errors it will display a url in the console that I can click on which will take me directly to the error source. I need to debug a js error specific to IE. IE is displaying the warning in the Console as:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Unable to get property 'children' of undefined or null reference TypeError: Unable to get property 'children' of undefined or null reference
  at a (http://localhost:63419//js/app.min.js:28:26002)
  at Anonymous function (http://localhost:63419//js/app.min.js:28:26178)
  at j (http://localhost:63419//js/app.min.js:2:29581)
  at Anonymous function (http://localhost:63419//js/app.min.js:2:29902) undefined
```

No urls are provided in this IE message.  Is there a way to enable clickable urls for IE browser warnings? Otherwise, does the following reference mean that I need to manually navigate to line 28 or 26002 of app.min.js?:

```
app.min.js:28:2600
```

Comment: I would guess it is filename:lineNumber:position. It may help if you replace it with a de-minified version of the js

Comment: it seems like chrome somehow does this automatically for me.  is there a way I can configure a setting for this in ie?